# google developer console does not fit explanation

Tags: youtube-api

I work with the newest chrom and IE browsers and I try to register to youtube api.
The google docomentation direct me to google developer consol but the web page that is
comming does not fit to the explanation they give it includs only (in the left slider) projects, billing and accounts and not what they give in the explanation (APIs & auth, Registered apps, Register app etc...)
How can I get the corrected console?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a project and select it to view the other options.